# Retrieve very specific values from string in VBA Excel

Tags: regex, excel, vba, string

A trading software called Rotman Interactive Trader is pushing into Excel some crude oil supply 'news' aka the strings, which follow more or less this format:

> WEEK 3 CL ACTUAL BUILD 12 MLB BBLS VS FORECAST BUILD 4 MLN BBLS

I basically would like to grab the 12 and the 4, and subtract them (12-4=8). However, it is also possible for the news to be:

> WEEK 3 CL ACTUAL BUILD 12 MLB BBLS VS FORECAST **DRAW** 4 MLN BBLS

In this example my calculation would be (12+4=16). It is also possible for the first 'BUILD' to be a 'DRAW'

Ideally, I would like to code a function which returns this array or similar, per the first example.

```
[0][0] = BUILD
[0][1] = 14
[1][0] = BUILD
[1][1] = 4
```

Sadly I am not fluent in VBA Excel and would like some help or ideas on how to achieve this. All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is a perfect example where you'd use Regular Expressions aka regex. I'm sure there are millions of regex experts here providing you a solution

Comment: Have a search on here for regex q&a...

Comment: So for each entry, you want four results?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is the simplest option I think.  Please have a look at the code below, it can be adapted as a custom function:

```
Sub SimpleRegex()

    Dim RegEx As Object, str As String
    Dim objMatch As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim result As String
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    str = "WEEK 3 CL ACTUAL BUILD 12 MLB BBLS VS FORECAST DRAW 4 MLN BBLS"

    With RegEx
      .Global = True
      .Pattern = "\b(BUILD|DRAW) ([0-9]*)\b"
    End With

    Set objMatch = RegEx.Execute(str)

    Debug.Print objMatch.Item(0)
    Debug.Print objMatch.Item(1)

End Sub
```

It can also be done with in-cell formulas but they would get a little convoluted.

Comment: Just what I needed!! Thank you